# .htaccess URL rewrite subfolder $_GET

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, get

I am trying to create a htaccess file for my website. I got subfolders called admin. In that subfolder is an *index.php* and some content pages. I want to rewrite my url's to *domain.com/admin/page1* as example.

Everything is working for my main index files but I can't get `$_GET['page']` working in the admin folder.

URL: http://techniekquiz.schl.nl/ http://techniekquiz.schl.nl/admin/
My htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?page=$1
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ admin/index.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)admin/(.*)$ ?page=$1
```

My *index.php* (admin/index.php) file (only `$_GET` part of it)

```
$page = (isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : '');
        if (!empty($page) && file_exists(''.$page.'.php'))
        {   
            require (''.$_GET['page'].'.php');
        }
        elseif ( ( (!file_exists(''.$page.'.php')) OR (!file_exists(''.$page.'.php'))  ) && !empty($page))
        {
            require('404.php');
        }
        else
        {
            require('dashboard.php');
        }
```

Comment: `[NC,L]` the `L` stands for 'last' - so if this rule matches, no other will be fired. Maybe you could provide us an example of what you want to have. URL that you type into browser and URL that reaches the server.

Comment: Thanks, added url: http://techniekquiz.schl.nl/ and http://techniekquiz.schl.nl/admin/

Comment: U should add a whitelist array to that kind of script for some level of security tho..